# State disappears after update using React setState hook when using nested fields/object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my example below, when I update a certain field, the other field in my state object disappears/unset and I get a warning about inputs becoming uncontrolled. Example below:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ 
    firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Poppins',
  });
  
  return (
    <div>
      First Name: <input value={user.firstName} onChange={e => { 
        setUser({firstName: e.target.value});
      }} />
      <br />
      Last Name: <input value={user.lastName} onChange={e => { 
        setUser({lastName: e.target.value});
      }} />
      <br />
      {JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the React docs state:

> However, unlike `this.setState` in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.

So using `setUser` does not do a shallow merge of the object, instead it replaces the state with the entire object, which causes the other field to disappear. You could use `Object.assign` or spread (`...`) operator to merge the objects together when doing `setUser`.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ 
    firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Poppins',
  });
  
  return (
    <div>
      First Name: <input value={user.firstName} onChange={e => { 
        setUser(Object.assign({}, user, {firstName: e.target.value}));
      }} />
      <br />
      Last Name: <input value={user.lastName} onChange={e => { 
        setUser(Object.assign({}, user, {lastName: e.target.value}));
      }} />
      <br />
      {JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Alternatively, create a custom hook called [`useMergeState`](https://github.com/beizhedenglong/react-hooks-lib/blob/master/src/hooks/useMergeState.js) to help you do merging automatically like in the usual `setState`.